# Why do we get a different result when we calculate it by parts?

Tags: elasticity, stress-strain

Assume a wire is 5 m long and we want to find how much force is required for increasing the length of it 5 m and make it 10 m long.

$$F = \frac{YAl}{L}\, .$$

If Y=5 and A=1 we will find the answer 5. But if we calculate it by parts the calculation doesn't match.
If we calculate how much force is required for increasing its length 1m and making it 6m long and then force required for making 6 m to 7 m and then 7 m to 8 m, 9 m to 10 m. And then we calculate the sum of the forces but we find a different answer. Why?

Comment: What is $F$, $Y$, $A$, $l$, $L$?

Comment: you should show us the calculation you did.  Did you account for the wire getting thinner?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that by "l" you mean the change in length, $ l= L-L_0 $ where $ L_0 $ is the initila length and $ L$ is thelength after deformation. With this notation, and calling the initial length "l",  Hooke's law is $$ F=YA\frac{\Delta l}{l} $$
Now you have to remember that this law holds only for small deformations. This means when the ration $ \frac{\Delta l}{l} $ is small enough. What is "small enough" depends in general on the material. Metals are quite elastic materials (compared with glass or concrete). The maximum ratio $ \frac{\Delta l}{l} $ for which they are still behaving like elastic materials (so Hooke's law holds) is of the order of fractions of percent.
So the formula will give wrong results even for a stretch of 1m. Even more so for doubling the 5 m length.

Now, assuming a very elastic material, like a very stretchy rubber (even though rubber may behave in a tricky way) which obeys Hooke's law even if you double its length, you will get the same value of the force, of course.
For your case, assuming  $ F=k{\Delta l} $ where $ k=YA\frac{1}{l} $, we'll have
For extension from 5 m to 10 m: $$ F=k(10m-5m)=(5m)k  $$
For gradual extensions, each extension by one meter adds a contribution to the force $$ \Delta F = (1 m) k $$
As you have 5 contributions (5 m to 6 m, 6 to 7, 7 to 8, 8 to 9 and 9 to 10) then the total force will be again (5m) k.

For a more realistic material, if you want to calculate the force to produce the large deformation, you can start by assuming that for small deformation Hooke's law holds and integrate the various force contributions:
$$ dF=YA \frac{dl}{l} $$
where l is the length of the wire after it was stretched by the amount dl. 
The force required to stretch the wire from $l_0$ to $ l $ will be
$$ F=YA \int ^l_{l0} \frac{dl}{l} = YA\times \ln(\frac{l}{l_0}) $$ 
Here l is the final length.
In terms of deformation this is 
$$ F= YA\times \ln(\frac{l_0+\Delta l}{l_0})=YA\times \ln(1+\frac{\Delta l}{l_0}) $$ 
Only for small values of the ratio $ \frac{\Delta l}{l} $ this can be approximated to
$$ F= YA\times \frac{\Delta l}{l_0} $$

Comment: Why A is constant?Isnt it changing?